# What is this "Supersonic French" aircraft?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

To celebrate Bastille Day, [Ubisoft released](https://twitter.com/rainbow6game/status/1281309676316041216) the below (2D) in-game charm for their game, *Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six Siege*.

[image: Supersonic French]

Despite frantic searching on Wikipedia, I cannot for the life of me figure out what aircraft the charm is based on, or if indeed a real-world equivalent exists at all. At first it looked like a Rafale, but the vertical stabilizer does not seem to fit any that I could find an image of.

It's not a question of life and death, but I would very much be interested in what aircraft is actually portrayed here.

Comment: It may not be a real one at all.

Comment: the [alpha jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault/Dornier_Alpha_Jet) is not supersonic.

Comment: The rafale would have canards anyway. Anything mirage would be supersonic but delta winged. They don't look like the Jaguar or the endenard/super endenard

Comment: @ManuH The naming used by Ubisoft is misleading; Alpha Jet is not indeed supersonic, but whoever responsible for naming at Ubisoft decided to name it as such.

Comment: The "[Patrouille de France](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HvWJgZtouY)" (aerobatic section of French Air Force) flies over Champs-Elysées on each July 14th (aka "Bastille day" elsewhere), the national day, to close the aerial military parade. They have Alpha-Jet currently, recognizable to their pronounced anhedral wing for reduced stability.

Comment: @mins I though anhedral wing where meant to improve stability as discussed in [this answer](/a/6293/3394)

Comment: @ManuH: "*The combination of aft sweep and high-wing configuration together achieve so much stability that it has to be counteracted with an anhedral*" ([source](https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_7_WingDesign.pdf), p 7-37). Many fighters have a negative dihedral angle for agility. Sweep (and twist) also affects the stability (according to Raymer 1° of dihedral is equivalent to 10° of sweep). (you can visualize the recovery effect of the dihedral/anhedral [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26759/how-does-the-dihedral-angle-work/26774#26774)).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe this is the [Alpha Jet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault/Dornier_Alpha_Jet)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source of pictures: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault/Dornier_Alpha_Jet)

It is famously used by the [Patrouille de France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrouille_de_France) (the French military acrobatic demonstration unit). They are most famous for overflying the Champs-Élysées during the July 14 celebration, drawing a French flag in the sky.

Comment: It is the Alphajet, and contrary to the OP, it is not supersonic

Comment: This is the correct answer

Comment: Actually contrary to Ubisoft, they named it such for whatever reason ;) Seems like it would be the Alpha Jet indeed, the vertical stabilizer is just modelled different for whatever copyright reason. Thanks!

Comment: Added some context to explain the choice. Feel free to roll back/edit.

Comment: @Antzi I left the bulk of it in there just for esoteric reasons, but it doesn't explain why I chose that aircraft. I chose it based on the appearance and that it's an aircraft used by the French military.

Comment: Actually....  pretty sure someone just traced [an image of a model of the alpha jet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otNJm.png) from an [online gift store for the patrouille](https://www.boutiquedelapatrouilledefrance.fr/en/les-incontournables/43-maquette-alpha-jet-paf.html). Sneaky sneaky :D

Comment: Re above-- nice find; deserves to be incorporated into an answer.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Ubisoft is so lazy

Comment: I suppose this is why aerospace engineers stick to engineering and video game creators stick to creating videogames.