# Is the Boeing AC-25A Banshee a real concept or a gimmick?

Tags: military, boeing, boeing-747, experimental-aircraft, us-air-force

Could this be a feasible concept [aircraft](http://aviationhumor.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/AirplaneJokes-0027.jpg) to replace the AC-130?

Comment: I think "gimmick" would be a step up for this bit of nonsense, honestly.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the URL should give it away already ...

The AC-130 is a [turboprop aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/why-are-propeller-engines-uncommon-on-commercial-aircraft/1088#1088) with relatively low wing loading. It can be operated from (almost) unprepared airstrips.

Now compare it to the 747-400: Higher minimum speed means more distance to the taget, higher [tire pressure](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/can-jet-airplanes-operate-on-rough-airfields/7496?s=2%7C0.2471#7496) means operation from established airbases with a long runway. Just look at the T-tail: Such a change would necessitate a complete redesign of the rear fuselage and the vertical tail. With the changes photoshopped into the picture the "AC-25" would be 80% new and could use only a few parts from the 747.

Here is an incomplete list of what needs to be changed:

- Lifting the wing up to a high wing position would need less dihedral ([or even some anhedral](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/why-does-an-225-have-anhedral-wings-though-it-is-a-cargo-aircraft?s=2%7C0.9350), to be precise), so the wing needs major modifications
- The landing gear would need a complete redesign. Currently, some parts retract into the wing, which is no longer there. The pods at the side of the fuselage are too small to hold the current gear.
- The mid fuselage section is a new design, too. Moving the wing up means a complete redesign of the bulkheads and wing attachment points. Also, fuel lines and cables need to be re-routed.

Comment: URL was the first thing I looked at (I tend to look at URLs before clicking - it's a habit).  Someone's made a cute JPG and pasted a Boeing logo on it.