# Why does the Falcon 900 have anhedral wings?

Tags: aircraft-design, dassault-falcon

Why does it have anhedral wings and not "normal" wings? Many other similar aircraft with low-wing have dihedral wings.
[image]
Source: [DassaultFalcon.com](http://www.dassaultfalcon.com/en/Aircraft/PreOwned/Pages/Pre-owned_list.aspx)

Edit: This is about the Falcon 900, which apparently has a low-wing design and it's not used for cargo like the An-225

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does An-225 have anhedral wings though it is a cargo aircraft?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/why-does-an-225-have-anhedral-wings-though-it-is-a-cargo-aircraft)

Comment: Aside from the size difference, the same effects should apply on the Falcon 900.

Comment: @fooot but this has not high wings, so there is a fundamental difference.

Comment: @Federico right, that too, but it still has the wing sweep, and the fact that it's only very slight anhedral.

Comment: I'm not an aerodynamics expert, but the raised horizontal stabiliser is a clue - T-Tails seem to have pretty neutral dihedral as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the same reason why the [Lockheed F-104 Starfighter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter) had such a pronounced anhedral: It is the size and location of the vertical tail.

[image: Lockheed F-104 Starfighter]

Lockheed F-104 Starfighter (picture [source](http://www.yellowairplane.com/Museums/images/F-104_Starfighter_Afterburners_Lit.jpg)).

In both cases, the vertical tail is large relative to the wing and fully above the roll axis. In a sideslip it produces a high rolling moment, so any more rolling moment from the wing would reduce the handling qualities of the aircraft.

Especially in case of the F-104, the raised position of the horizontal tail shifts the center of pressure on the vertical tail upwards, exacerbating the offset location of the vertical tail.

The rear-mounted engines on the Falcon 900 move the center of gravity backwards, so the wing is more backwards than usual for aircraft with wing-mounted engines. Therefore, the part of the fuselage ahead of the center of gravity is large, requiring a larger vertical tail to overcome the destabilizing yawing moment of the fuselage.

The same is true for the [Tupolev 134](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-134) and [154](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tupolev_Tu-154), and - surprise! - they also have no dihedral, even though both are low-wing configurations.

[image: Tupolev 154M of the Polish Air Force]

Tupolev 154M of the Polish Air Force (picture [source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Polish_Air_Force_Tupolev_Tu-154M_Lebeda.jpg/800px-Polish_Air_Force_Tupolev_Tu-154M_Lebeda.jpg))

Comment: I wonder if the DC-9 and B727 would be good comparison points as well....

Answer (score 0):

[image][Picture source](https://www.dassault-aviation.com/en/passion/aircraft/civil-dassault-aircraft/falcon-900/)

It may seem so when on ground, but in flight the wings flex up. Judging from the photo, the wings seem to have the tiniest bit of dihedral. They also have wing sweep, which provides [sideslip-to-roll stability](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/66331/21091) as well.

Comment: A swept wing can create a visual illusion re dihedral or anhedral from any angle other than straight-on from the front.  I would be cautious about concluding that that photo shows dihedral.  I would very surprised if the wing flexed enough to remove all the anhedral visible in the photo of the plane on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

It's because anhedral wings remove one of the biggest disadvantages of dihedral wings - maneuverability. Although dihedral wings give roll stability by pushing up on the wing which is lowered while banking, it also means that whenever the pilot is rolling to one particular direction, the wings have a tendency to oppose that by rolling the aircraft to the opposite direction, giving the aircraft reduced maneuverability. But anhedral wings don't come with such a problem.