# Other than looking cool, what is the reason behind the TSR-2's anhedral wingtips?

Tags: aerodynamics, military, wing

Pretty much what the title says. What is the purpose of the TSR-2's anhedral wingtips? I've heard someone say that they use it to counter yawing I think but is this the true reason or is it something else?[image: TSR-2 front profile with wingtips visible]

Comment: Although it looks cool it's one of the few airplanes I wouldn't want to fly. Something about it makes my spider sense tingle.

Answer (score 13):

In the document "[TSR2 with Hindsight](https://www.rafmuseum.org.uk/documents/research/RAF-Historical-Society-Journals/Journal-17B-TSR2-with-Hindsight.pdf)", a lengthy documentation of TSR2 development by the Royal Air Force Historical Society, the reason given for the wingtip anhedral is the correction of lateral and longitudinal stability. Being a [high-wing design](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/6285/why-does-an-225-have-anhedral-wings-though-it-is-a-cargo-aircraft), the anhedral was used to lower the sideslip-induced rolling moment.

To quote from TSR2 with hindsight:

> At re-freeze, the wing was moved, its planform changed slightly and the tips given anhedral to reconcile lateral and longitudinal stability requirements; a very complex joint rib resulted. The wing already had a centre-line joint but only after great resistance from the weight-saving auditors.

The re-freeze in turn was the result of supersonic wind tunnel testing in 1960:

> It was not until March 1960 that supersonic wind-tunnel test results were again available and one effect of the resultant design re-freeze was further refinement of the rear fuselage lines.

Turning down wingtips had been employed before in a high-wing design where re-designing the complete wing had been out of the question: The [Heinkel 162](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinkel_He_162). Here, the name for that modification was "Lippisch-Ohren" (Lippisch ears) after the person who had proposed them first for his [delta-winged designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippisch_Delta_IV).

Comment: So if I follow right, they're there to stop the plane from pitching up and down and rolling where they don't want it.

Comment: @PeterKämpf  How does wingtip anhedral affect **longitudinal** stability?

Comment: @AdityaSharma I was wondering myself, I guess it affects pitch moments at high AoA. Planform changes are more effective and I think the change was mostly about dihedral effect.

Comment: @AdityaSharma: obviously via "*longitudinal dihedral*" 

Comment: @AdityaSharma moves the Neutral Point aft for both the longitudinal and vertical axis I would say.

Comment: @PeterKämpf the CL-214 water bomber uses similar tips for the opposite purpose,to restore dihedral effect degraded by the fin-like nacelles of the PW-120 turboprops, which had an effect like changing from high wing to mid wing.

Comment: Remember the anhedrals are put on the tips of a *delta* [wing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_TSR-2)  They will help *bottom lift* there, moving the center of lift aft as AoA increases.  This is essentially how a tail responds to an unwanted pitch-up.  Once the "longitudinal dihedral" does its job setting wing AoA, all forces are in balance for a given airspeed.  If sudden headwind gust pitches the nose up, the anhedralled wing tips adds to the effect of the *horizontal stabilizer* to prevent the elevator (or pilot) from overpitching the aircraft.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni This would make sense at supersonic speed, but given that the TSR2 was already stable at subsonic speed, there was no need to increase longitudinal stability at supersonic speed.

Comment: @JohnK Intresting. Is there a neutral point for vertical axis? and which direction is considered "aft"?

Comment: So, as ever, its a "fix" for a design issue that could not be resolved easily any other way.  Same reason that the F-4 Phantom has turned up wings and turned down tail planes - to fix the poor aero dynamics of the design.

Comment: Yes because static stability in the pitch and yaw axis are the same thing, "weathervaning" about the CofG into the airstream, except in pitch you have to include trimming forces to vary the weathervaning target angle. If NP is the point at which all aerodynamic forces are focused, and it needs to be aft of the C of G for the weathervane (static stability) effect to work, the vertical profile of the wing tips, being aft of the C of G on a delta would increase yaw static margin slightly by moving the vertical aerodynamic center aft, and the plan area would increase pitch static margin slightly.